# Font-size of aligned multiline subscript

Tags: fontsize, alignment, subscripts

Consider the below single-line and multi-line subscripts.

```
a_{1,2,3}
```

```
b_{
    \substack{
    1, 2, 3  \\
  + 4, 5, 6
    }
}
```

> [image]

I wish to align the `1` and `4` in the multiline `b` subscript. Merely changing `substack` to an `aligned` environment however affects the font-size of the subscript.

```
b_{
    \begin{aligned}
    & 1, 2, 3  \\
  + & 4, 5, 6
    \end{aligned}
}
```

> [image]

Use of `aligned` has increased the subscript font-size to be that of non-subscripted text. Haphazardly `\scriptscriptstyle` does not seem to affect the font-size.

```
b_{
    \scriptscriptstyle
    \begin{aligned}
    \scriptscriptstyle
    & 1, 2, 3  \\
    \scriptscriptstyle
  + & 4, 5, 6
    \end{aligned}
}
```

How can I create alignment in multi-line subscripts while preserving the subscript font-size?

Answer (score 2):

Insert a `\phantom` component that matches the component causing the misalignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  & a_{1,2,3} \\
  & b_{
    \substack{
      \phantom{+} 1, 2, 3  \\
               +  4, 5, 6
    }}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I'd also consider inserting `\!\!` (two negative thinspaces) between `b_{` and `\substack`, to "snug up" the two-line subscript material to its parent (`b`).

Comment: Ahh my actual use-case precludes a simple solution like `phantom`, since the subscripted expressions are complicated equations which need a more complicated alignment. This is the curse of stack exchange - it is impossible to create a minimum working example that satisfies the pedants while not misleading the answers! :^)

Comment: @AntiEarth: Depending on your complicated setup, `\phantom` should still do the trick.